# Android application doesn't exits nor goes to background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-activity

I have created a Android contact-book application. But when I enter the application, go through 3-4 screens and accordingly various activities are called. After which if I press the back button repetitively I return on first screen of the application.

If here I press back button some or the other previously visited screen is shown again, rather the application should either exit or should go in background.

Where have I missed out some standards that causes me to be stuck?

In short, the back-button on the first-screen of application shows irrelevant previously visited screens of the Android application. So I'm unable to move application in background or exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can have these causes:

- **The application wasn't closed before**

If you are developing with Eclipse and the emulator and old version of your application does not necessarily get killed if you fix something and test the application again. Eclipse only tells the emulator *to start the main activity*.

So your Activity stack possibly looked this:

```
Main Activity -> Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity A
```

thus pressing `back` from the last one will bring up the Activities in the order

```
Activity B -> Activity A -> Main Activity -> Home-Screen
```

if you do not exit the application and just let the emulator create the Main-Activity again this will happen:

```
Main Activity -> Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity A -> Main Activity
```

Thus any actions from that point on will extend the activity stack but does not necessarily clean the old entries out of your stack. (this will only happen if the system considers them not necessary anymore and kills them)

- **Overriden methods**

It is possible (but unlikely) that you have caused this behaviour yourself.

If you did not override methods such as `onPause()` you most certainly did not cause this. Some apps are forcing the start of an activity in the onPause()-method (which is very bad style, since this is not expected behaviour). This could change your activity stack.

Comment: In my case it seems to be the issue with **Overriden Methods** . I want to show login screen if the application is coming from background, so I kept a variable in Intent during onPause method of each activity. Hence, in each case I have overriden `onPause()` method, but I haven't started any activity from `onPause()` though.  
Do you still think this is what the problem is all about ?

Comment: please provide the code of your onPause()-methods and the code segments where you start activities. It's hard to tell without any of this.

Comment: I need to check whether the app is coming from background,so I created Base-Classes by for activities for different purposes & overriden `onPause()`. `@Override
 public void startActivity(Intent intent)
 {
  super.startActivity(intent);
  setGlobalIntentVariable(intent);
  super.finish();
 }
 public void setGlobalIntentVariable(Intent p_intent)
 {
  p_intent.putExtra("app", "ContactZ");
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  getIntent().putExtra("activity", this.getClass().getName().toString());
  onSaveInstanceState(getIntent().getExtras());
  super.onPause();
 }`  Please Format. Thanks

Comment: Also I have used startActivity many a times depending upon events occured, as per the requirement. Rather using the new Indent everytime I reused the indent as : `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = getIntent(); 
    i.setClass(getApplicationContext(),AAddEditContact.class);
    i.putExtra(ContactZDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    
    i.putExtra("app","ContactZ");
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    onDestroy();
   }
  });` @stefan,please let me know if u need nything

Comment: you should put that code in your question, it's hardly readable this way :D what i think may cause the error in your code is the order of commands you're using: you first let the super-class start the activity `intent` and afterwards put some data to it. that seems wrong. also i do not understand what the `super.finish()` does in this context. can you try it with  `@Override public void startActivity(Intent intent) {setGlobalIntentVariable(intent); super.startActivity(intent); }` please?

Comment: I'll try, but by adding so big code to question will create question more complecated, causing less no. of answers. So prefered to send you the code in comment itself, as I'm bit selfish about getting the answer sooner ;) Thanks, will try to work on the code u suggested here.

Comment: your question is a bit hard without any code provided. as you are overriding such important methods as startActivity it would be the best way to post a good question with all the relevant code. I'm sure you will get good answers if you put your code there.

Comment: Also, I have called `finish();` to finish/end the current activity while starting the other one, isn't it valid ? Might be too silly question, as I am a new-bee to this Android arena !  @stefan Please suggest !

Comment: Rather I am confused how to prrovide the complete code of this big application. But thanks @stefan for the suggestion will definitely ask one, and would let you know about the link :)

Comment: I have no clue how to solve this. maybe you can help me understand the problem by adding a bit of lig file. just add to the onCreate, onResume, onPause, onStop a bit of code saying Log.d("activity A","create") and so on. then collect the data from log cat and post it here. this will help understand how the activity stack looks like.

Comment: Log file is copied in the question itself, please check the same, and let me know if u need any further details. Thanks !!!

Comment: unfortunately that's not sufficient. Plus it looks like hell. Please implement Log outputs for "paused", "stopped" and "resumed" activities and filter all other log output.

Comment: Isn't it necessary to have `super.onPause()` first thing in the overridden method `onPause()` ?